# Not outputting newline in php

Tags: php

```
$whichwrong = "The following questions were not answered correctly: \n\n";
$whichwrong .= "Question Number: $questionNum || Your Answer: $userAnswers[$s][$q]\n";
echo $whichwrong;
```

Displays:

> The following questions were not answered correctly: Question Number:
>   2 || Your Answer: b Question Number: 4 || Your Answer: c Question
>   Number: 5 || Your Answer: a Question Number: 1 || Your Answer: b
>   Question Number: 3 || Your Answer: b Question Number: 1 || Your
>   Answer: b Question Number: 2 || Your Answer: a Question Number: 1 ||
>   Your Answer: b Question Number: 2 || Your Answer: b

Why is the `"\n"` not working correctly?

Meanwhile this works just fine:

```
$totalValue .= "Correct: {$correct}\n";
$totalValue .= "Wrong: {$wrong}\n";
```

Comment: whitespace is collapsed in the browser, view source and you will see your newlines, use a <br> element instead for a hard break;

Comment: Use `\r\n` - `\r` is a Carriage Return, `\n` is a New Line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `nl2br` for inserting html-linebreaks (`<br />`)

```
echo nl2br($whichwrong);
```

Normal `\n` are treated by browsers like normal whitespaces.

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function: n12br() in /home/web/i/imed.com/htdocs/test.php on line 205`

Comment: nl = new line. ;) not new 1

Comment: Ok Sorry that solved it! I updated my question, to show how come another lines of code works just fine?

Comment: aaaaaahhhhhhhh... didnt read it correctly. makes sense now :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're viewing it in a browser, you need to use `<br>` - you can also use the `nl2br()` function. If you're in the console, try `\r\n`